# Save XNA rendered image to disk

Tags: c#, 3d, xna

I am trying to save an image rendered in XNA to disk. This is actually quite easy, but the kicker is I need the full 32 bit float precision for each channel not just the 0-255 range.

I have been looking into using texture packing (converting the float into a 4 component ARGB), but I worry I will lose precision this way. I need very high accuracy.

Another way I was looking into is using a shader and multiply the float component with 2147483647 (max positive int), then go through each bit and store a binary 0 or 1 in the rendered image. Each image can later be reassembled in regular code to reconstruct the full precision float. This works, but the problem is, shader model 3.0 seems to not support 32 bit int's properly. All I get is 24 bit of precision this way.

Is there a way to do this in a more direct and accurate way?

Comment: I take it you're rendering to a texture, and then saving it? In which case, can't you just render to a texture with a Vector4 format, and save that?

Answer (score 0):

Since you say that you're using 32-bit precision for each of your four channels, I assume that your texture is using `SurfaceFormat.Vector4`, which is--as far I'm aware--the only 128-bit texture format supported by XNA.  In that case, it's easy enough to retrieve the actual data from a texture that you've rendered:

```
var tex = new Texture2D(GraphicsDevice, 1024, 1024, false, SurfaceFormat.Vector4);
var data = new Vector4[1024 * 1024];
tex.GetData<Vector4>(data);
```

Then all you need to do is write some code to save the `data` array to a file that you can read in later, which is easy enough.  Then you can reconstitute the texture:

```
Vector4[] data = LoadMyData();
tex.SetData(data);
```